# What wrong with the below Reg Expression?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replicate a Reg Ex.. But my code is giving always true irrespective of the value i pass..

It would be much helpful.. if u can explain what exactly this reg Ex is doing...

```js
var re = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9-`.'_]?)+");

if(re.test('valueFromHtml'){
 console.log("valid");
}else{
    console.log("invalid");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) — why not simply use an online tool like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/#javascript)?

Answer (score 2):

```
var re = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9-`.'_]?)+");
```

Your regular expression means, "one or more occurrences of a member of this particular set of characters, or no characters". Your pattern therefore matches the zero-character empty string, which is part of any possible test string.